# add array of objects to array - typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class:

```
export class Party {
  constructor ( public title: string,
            public lan1: number,
            public lan2: number ) { }
}
```

I have a service:

```
import { Party } from '../classes/party';

export class PartyService {

 parties: Party[] = [];

  addData(title: string, lan1: number, lan2: number) {
    this.parties.push(new Party(title, lan1, lan2));
  }

  getData(): Party[] {
    return this.parties;
   }

}
```

I have a component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
parties: Party[] = [];

title = 'app';

party_location: Location[] =  [
  { lat: 123, lng: 23 }
];

constructor(private partyService: PartyService){}

ngOnInit() {

  this.parties = this.partyService.getData();
 }
```

}

And I want to add parties properties to party_location like this:

> for (let item in this.parties) {
>         this.party_location.push(new Location(item.lan1, item.lan2));
>       }

But I can't because typescript doesn't see lan1 lan2 properties in item.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `for..of` to iterate the array. `for..in` iterates the properties of an object, `for..of` iterates an array elements:

```
for (let item of this.parties) { 
   this.party_location.push(new Location(item.lan1, item.lan2)); 
}
```

Comment: @yuracr9 glad to help, don't forget to upvote and park as answered :)